# How to debug apache stall

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout

I have a Drupal web server vps under centos 6.3 that has been running well since February.

In the last few days, the site has started going down: tcp connects, then it waits indefinitely.

If I restart httpd, the site becomes responsive for a few minutes before grinding to a halt again.

There is plenty of disk space, the cpu is idle, and about half the system memory is in buffers and cache. Mysqld remains responsive.

If I run pstack on the httpd worker processes, they seem to be stuck in the same place:

```
#0  0x00007f568d9c3a28 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f568deb6717 in apr_wait_for_io_or_timeout () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
#2  0x00007f568deb1a28 in apr_socket_sendv () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
#3  0x00007f568f3d3083 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f568f3d4035 in ap_core_output_filter ()
#5  0x00007f568f3e6194 in ap_http_chunk_filter ()
#6  0x00007f568f3e46db in ap_http_header_filter ()
#7  0x00007f568f3c8fd0 in ap_content_length_filter ()
#8  0x00007f568f3e6443 in ap_byterange_filter ()
#9  0x00007f568f3df9fc in ap_filter_flush ()
#10 0x00007f568f3c6f8e in ap_rwrite ()
#11 0x00007f5689814f76 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#12 0x00007f568974e36b in php_ub_body_write_no_header () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#13 0x00007f568974e998 in php_end_ob_buffer () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#14 0x00007f568974f32f in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#15 0x00007f568974e998 in php_end_ob_buffer () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#16 0x00007f568974f051 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#17 0x00007f56897db0c8 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#18 0x00007f56897b2400 in execute () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#19 0x00007f568978cb3d in zend_execute_scripts () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#20 0x00007f568973ada8 in php_execute_script () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#21 0x00007f5689815a85 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#22 0x00007f568f3d4b00 in ap_run_handler ()
#23 0x00007f568f3d83be in ap_invoke_handler ()
#24 0x00007f568f3e386c in ap_internal_redirect ()
#25 0x00007f568b82a7a5 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
#26 0x00007f568f3d4b00 in ap_run_handler ()
#27 0x00007f568f3d83be in ap_invoke_handler ()
#28 0x00007f568f3e3a30 in ap_process_request ()
#29 0x00007f568f3e08f8 in ?? ()
#30 0x00007f568f3dc608 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#31 0x00007f568f3e8807 in ?? ()
#32 0x00007f568f3e8b1a in ?? ()
#33 0x00007f568f3e979c in ap_mpm_run ()
#34 0x00007f568f3c0900 in main ()
```

Any suggestions where to look next in debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `strace -p PID_OF_APACHE -f` to debug the output.  Also, maybe you need to update your Apache version and/or one or more of its dependencies - or even Drupal if that isn't updated too.

You might want to check with the changelogs of the services above to see if there any known issues.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows php flushing the output buffer, and waiting for the browser to respond.

You should make a network trace, see if traffic from certain clients is not unrealistically slow. It could be a [slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris) attack.